# Overloading operator[] changing value

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm trying to overload an int array, so basically if I have this in my main func

```
IntArray arr(10); 
for(int i = 0; 0 < 10; i++)
  a[i] = i * 10;
```

I was able to get

```
a[0] = 0, a[1] =10, a[2]=20.... so on
```

I was able to make this one work.

If I then do

```
IntArray arr(-3, 10)
```

with same for loop, I was able to get the appropriate answer as well.
BUT...
If I do

```
IntArray arr(6, 8)`
```

using same for loop I get c[6] = 1, c[7]=1, c[8] =0
I been trying to figure this out since yesterday, here's my code:

```
//---------------------Header file

#ifndef INTARRAY_H_
#define INTARRAY_H_

#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class IntArray
{

private:
    int first;
    int last;
    int size;

    string arrName;
    int* arrPtr;


public:
    IntArray();
    int& operator[](int i);

    IntArray(int num);
    IntArray(int num1, int num2);

    int low();
    int high();
    void setName(string str);
    //streams
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, IntArray& d);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, IntArray& d);

};

#endif /* INTARRAY_H_ */
//---------------------
```

My int array class:

```
#include "IntArray.h"



IntArray::IntArray(){
    size = 10;
    first = 0; last = 9;
    arrPtr = new int[size];
}

IntArray::IntArray(int num){
    size = num;
    first = 0; last = size-1;
    arrPtr = new int[size];
    //cout<<"\n the size "<<size<<endl;
    //arrPtr[3] = 123;

    //ex = 3;
}

IntArray::IntArray(int num1, int num2){
    first = num1; last = num2;
    size = last - first + 1;
    //cout<<"\n the size "<<size<<endl;
    arrPtr = new int[size];
}

int& IntArray::operator[](int i) {
    if (i >= (last+1)){
        cout<<"Error: Index out of range"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    return arrPtr[i];
}

int IntArray::getInt(int i){
    return arrPtr[i];
}

//======================
int IntArray::low(){
    return first;
}
int IntArray::high(){
    return last;
}
//======================
//==========OUT stream==========

// for cout << justName<< endl;
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, IntArray& aPtr) {
    for(int i = aPtr.low(); i <= aPtr.high(); i++){
        os << aPtr.arrName <<"[" << i << "] = " << aPtr[i] << " ";
    }

    return os;
}

void IntArray::setName(string str){
    arrName = str;
}
```

For some apparent reason, after using my setName function on this test function, it changes the value to c[6] = 1, c[7]=1, c[8] =0.

```
 void test3() {
    IntArray c(6, 8);
    for(int i = c.low(); i <= c.high(); i++)
        c[i] = i * 10;
    c.setName("c");
    cout << c << endl;

}
```

Let me make this one clear. Like I said, I did narrowed down my problem.

```
IntArray a(10)  //THIS ONE WORKS!
IntArray a(-3, 6) //THIS ONE WORKS!
IntArray a(6,8) //NOT working.
```

For the last one, the array outputs the right value, until I use the setName function.

Comment: We're not going to debug your code for you.  You should do some basic debugging first, to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Your `operator[]` is wrong. Remember your internal index 0 is not neccessarily the external index 0..

Comment: The size of your array is `8 - 6 + 1 = 3`. So `arrPtr[x]` where `x > 2` is not defined. Alter your thinking.

Comment: One thing, this isn't going to work with your IntArray as it stands now: `void foo(const IntArray& a) { int x = a[0]; }`  Your `operator[]` needs two overloads, not one.

Comment: Other side-notes: Your one- and no-argument ctors should be inline and just delegate to the two-argument version. The one-argument-ctor needs to be `explicit`. You are violating the rule of 3 (5), which will end badly: Care for the copy-ctor / op= (same for move). Your `op=` should probably not test for validity, though if it does `abort` is far more appropriate. I wonder how you'll implement `op>>`...

Comment: Maybe your IntArray 2-argument constructor should use the second argument as the number of elements, not the highest bound.  For example `IntArray(-3, 10)` would mean that the lowest bound is -3 and the array consists of 10 elements.  That would be more consistent with how a C++ 0-based array would work (you specify the number of elements).

Comment: @mostruash Pay more attention. I was aware of that. If you notice my for loop, it saids from a.low=0 <= a.high(last index). Alter your reading.

Comment: @xpluffy What are you talking about? It seems to me that `for(int i = c.low(); i <= c.high(); i++)` is equivalent to `for(int i = 6; i <= 8; i++)`.

Comment: @mostruash and that is to find arr[6],arr[7],arr[8]. I don't know what exactly is wrong with that.

Comment: @xpluffy But you do `arrPtr = new int[3]`. So `arrPtr[6]` is undefined.

Comment: @mostruash That's true, just to my understanding arrPtr = new int[3] is to reserve 3 int arr spaces in the memory. And when I did the for loop, I labeled those as arr[6],arr[7],arr[8], which wasn't so

Comment: @xpluffy When you do `arrPtr = new int[3]`, `arrPtr[i]` is defined if and only if `0 <= i < 3`. That's how arrays work in many programming languages. You are mixing arrays with dictionary-like data structures.

Answer (score 0):

In the subscript operator you also should check that `i` is not less than `first`.
Tale into account that relative to the pointer you have to use indices starting from zero. So instead of

```
return arrPtr[i];
```

you have to write

```
return arrPtr[i - first];
```

Also it would be better if constructor

```
IntArray(int num);
```

would be declared like

```
IntArray( size_t num);
```

and correspondingly data member `size` would have type `size_t`

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your only problem but it looks like you want to allow users of your class to use the old Perl [$[](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5B)

To support this you'll need to modify it in your `operator[]`:

```
int& IntArray::operator[](int i) {
    if (i > last || i < first ){
        cout<<"Error: Index out of range"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    } 
    return arrPtr[i - first];
}
```